# how to change kubernetes pod namespace

Tags: kubernetes

I am created a pod in default namespace in kubernetes,but now I want to move pod to dabai-fat namespace I current created.I am trying to modify the yaml file but it give error:

```
the namespace of the object (dabai-fat) does not match the namespace on the request (default)
```

what should I do to make it work,should I delete the old pod and created a new pod?

Comment: Try this ->  kubectl get pod <pod> -n<namespace> -o yaml --export mypod.yml  ; 
kubectl apply --namespace=<destination-namespace> –f mypod.yml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should delete the old pod and recreate the new pod in the desired namespace.

You cannot **move** kubernetes resources between namespaces. Combination of **name** and **namespace** identifies a resource uniquely. So you cannot move the resource to a different namespace as another resource might already be present in the other namespace with same name.